# Json_query filter over a loop result

Tags: ansible

Shell task:

```
  - name: shell task
    shell: "cat /tmp/test.txt"
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_batch }" ##running serial:10
    run_once: true
    register: test_result
    when: some_condition
```

Forming a dictionary with the register output:

```
    - name: Dictionary
      set_fact:
         _cdict: "{{ dict{ ansible_play_batch|zip(ansible_play_batch|map('extract', hostvars,'test_result'))) }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug: msg="{{ _cdict }}"
      run_once: true
```

This gives the below output on:

```
  ok: [abcd.com] => {
      "msg": {
           "abcd.com": {
                "changed": true,
                "failed": true,
                "msg": "All items completed",
                "results": [
                    {
                        ....
                        ....
                        "failed": true,
                        ....
                    }
                        "item": abcd,
                         ....
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                        ....
                        ....
                        "failed": true,
                        ....
                    }
                        "item": efgh,
                         ....
                     ]
                    },
           "efgh.com": {
                "changed": true,
                "failed": true,
                "msg": "All items completed",
                "results": [
                         {
                        ....
                        ....
                        "failed": true,
                        ....
                    }
                        "item": abcd,
                         ....
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                        ....
                        ....
                        "failed": true,
                        ....
                    }
                        "item": efgh,
                         ....
                     ]
                    }
```

Need to form the json_query filter that checks for "failed": true inside the results of each server-results and then return only the item value.

Tried below, not working and the one commented by Vladimir

```
 - name: filter
   set_fact:
      _itt: "{{ _previousFormedDict| dict2items|json_query('[?results.failed == `true`].results[0].item[]') }}"
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and make it [mre]. In particular, include valid minimal data.

Comment: Any further details required ? have added most of the details.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _itt: "{{ _previousFormedDict|dict2items|
                  json_query('[?value.failed].value.results[0].item') }}"
      vars:
        _previousFormedDict:
          abcd.com:
            changed: true
            failed: true
            msg: All items completed
            results: [{failed: true, item: ab}]
          efgh.com:
            changed: true
            failed: false
            msg: All items completed
            results: [{failed: true, item: cd}]
```

gives

```yaml
  _itt:
  - ab
```